# Firebase functions get the user phone number

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase Function to save the user info in onCreate, using auth trigger. Is there a way to get the users phone number if he authenticated using this method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As shown on the [Functions Github repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/54#issuecomment-305648052):

> Phone Auth now triggers Cloud Functions, as intended. Here's an example of the `UserRecord` object (in `event.data`) that you might receive:
>
> ```
> {
>   "metadata": {
>     "createdAt": "2017-06-01T23:01:23.000Z",
>     "lastSignedInAt": "2017-06-01T23:01:23.000Z"
>   },
>   "phoneNumber": "+1555123456",
>   "providerData": [
>     {
>       "providerId": "phone",
>       "uid": "+1555123456"
>     }
>   ],
>   "uid": "C6simWCCNlO3Mdyq9PYyY1O8qPJ3"
> }
> ```

The phone number is then available from the [`UserRecord.phoneNumber`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord#phoneNumber)